# How MVC architecture deal with multi roles users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm a big fan of Ruby on Rails & Laravel, that doesn't mean I don't follow the "edgy" tech stack, just because I like the simplicity of the mvc concept.

but I'm still confused about, how to deal with different views / business logic for the different user roles.

Let say, I have a project that has 3 types of users (Role) :

- Admin
- Editor
- Public

Let's just say they can all access `Post` **Model** with their own permissions.

which one the correct project structure? (mvc pov)

**1. Default**

The *default* what I mean is, does mvc expect all business logic to be set in the controllers? so that the controller will have thousands of lines of code, because it manages data scope & views for each one of them.

```
|-- App
|   |-- Models
|   |   |-- Post
|   |-- Controllers
|   |   |-- PostController
|   |-- Views
|   |   |-- Admin
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
|   |   |-- Editor
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
|   |   |-- Public
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
```

**2. Name Spaced Controller**

just like the name, each user type having a different namespace controller, so we can easily manage each one of them, but somehow I feel like this one chanhging the MVC structure itself.

```
|-- App
|   |-- Models
|   |   |-- Post
|   |-- Controllers
|   |   |-- Admin
|   |   |   |--PostController
|   |   |-- Editor
|   |   |   |--PostController
|   |   |-- Public
|   |   |   |--PostController
|   |-- Views
|   |   |-- Admin
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
|   |   |-- Editor
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
|   |   |-- Public
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
```

**3. Different Apps Each User Types**

When it comes to Ruby on Rails with their own "scaffold generator", do I have to make a different app for each users? but I think this one isn't solutions for "mvp" project right?

```
|-- Admin App 
|   |-- Models
|   |   |-- Post
|   |-- Controllers
|   |   |-- PostController
|   |-- Views
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
-----------------------------
|-- Editor
|   |-- Models
|   |   |-- Post
|   |-- Controllers
|   |   |-- PostController
|   |-- Views
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
-----------------------------
|-- Public
|   |-- Models
|   |   |-- Post
|   |-- Controllers
|   |   |-- PostController
|   |-- Views
|   |   |   |--post
|   |   |   |  |--index.views
|   |   |   |  |--show.views
|   |   |   |  |--edit.views
|   |   |   |  |--create.views
-----------------------------
```

please explain for me, maybe someone can provide a solution to this confusion. thanks

Comment: I dont even know if there is any recommended solution. I'd probably use the first one you describe, unless you are certain that the controller is different for each role. It boils down to not having to repeat any code because that's probably the nicest thing to have.

Comment: Also afaik the "MVC" concept only obliges you to separate models from controllers from views. So as long as you maintain that, anything is permitted :)

Comment: @Flame so in real world scenario, you choose the "deafult" one? even though there's a risk of having a "messy controller" ? why u aren't choosing number 2 ?

Comment: thats kinda the thing; I cant answer that for you, it depends on the amount of code repetition you will have. I'd still start with the default one, and if you notice that you need multiple controllers, then just start separating them using no. 2 (possibly using a base PostController from which you can extend). That way you can use `Controllers/PostController` as the base, and have others extend from it.

Comment: Boils down to whether you want to have a lot of if statements or a lot of files as well as how different the logic is for each user.

Comment: so according to above comments, that's doesn't matter in which project structure that I choose ? I mean mvc doesn't care about the project structure ? as long as I control the Model & Presentation via Controller?